# Inserting character dynamically into string in R

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to insert a "+" symbol into the middle of a postcode. The postcodes following a pattern of `AA111AA` or `AA11AA`. I want the "+" to be inserted before the final number, so an output of either `AA11+1AA` or `AA1+1AA`. I've found a way to do this using `stringr`, but it feels like there's an easier way to do this that how I'm currently doing it. Below is my code.

```
pc <- "bt43xx"

pc <- str_c(
      str_sub(pc, start = 1L, end = -4L), 
      "+", 
      str_sub(pc, start = -3L, end = -1L)
      )

pc
[1] "bt4+3xx"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some alternatives.  All solutions work if `pc` is a scalar or vector. No packages are needed.  Of them (3) seems particularly short and simple.

**1)** Match everything (`.*`) up to the last digit (`\\d`) and then replace that with the first capture (i.e. the match to the part within the first set of parens), a plus and the second capture (i.e. a match to the last digit).

```
sub("(.*)(\\d)", "\\1+\\2", pc)
```

**2)** An alternative which is even shorter is to match a digit followed by a non-digit and replace that with a plus followed by the match:

```
sub("(\\d\\D)", "+\\1", pc)
## [1] "bt4+3xx"
```

**3)** This one is even shorter than (2).  It matches the last 3 characters  replacing the match with a plus followed by the match:

```
sub("(...)$", "+\\1", pc)
## [1] "bt4+3xx"
```

**4)** This one splits the string into individual characters, inserts a plus in the appropriate position using `append` and puts the characters back together.

```
sapply(Map(append, strsplit(pc, ""), after = nchar(pc) - 3, "+"), paste, collapse = "")
## [1] "bt4+3xx"
```

If `pc` were known to be a scalar (as is the case in the question) it could be simplified to:

```
paste(append(strsplit(pc, "")[[1]], "+", nchar(pc) - 3), collapse = "")
[1] "bt4+3xx"
```

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression with `sub` and two back references should work.

```
sub("(\\d?)(\\d[^\\d]*)$", "\\1+\\2", pc)
[1] "bt4+3xx"
```

- \\d? matches 1 or 0 numeric characters, 0-9, and is captured by (). It will match if at least two numeric characters are present.
- \\d[^\\d]* matches a numeric character followed by all non numeric characters, and is captured by ()
- $ anchors the regular expression to the end of the string
- "\\1+\\2" replaces the matched elements in the first two points with themselves and a "+" in the middle.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit OP's need as the + is after the digits. I would do `sub("(.*)(\\d\\D{2})", "\\1+\\2", pc)`

Comment: Ugh. I missed that. Thank you for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub('(\\d)(?=\\D+$)','+\\1',pc,perl=T)
```